# Create record with all fields undefined, without triggering warning

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, suppress-warnings

I'd like to create a value of a record type that can be pattern-matched, without filling any fields.

```
data Foo = MkFoo
    { field1 :: Int
    , field2 :: Bool
    }

fun :: Foo -> Bool
fun MkFoo{..} = True

bar :: Bool
bar = fun MkFoo{}
```

This works because all fields of the `Foo` passed to `fun` are undefined, and `fun` is lazy in them. Of course, `fun undefined` would fail, because `fun` pattern-matches on the record constructor `MkFoo`.

However, this causes a compiler warning:

> • Fields of `MkFoo` not initialised: `field1`, `field2`

I would like to get rid of this warning *for this specific instance*. So I am not looking to turn off the warning in general (with `-Wno-missing-fields`). I am also not looking to change `fun` (I could just make the pattern matching on `MkFoo` irrefutable). I would also like to avoid having to write out all fields of `MkFoo`, as in

```
bar = fun MkFoo{ field1 = undefined, field2 = undefined }
```

Comment: This is similar to GDefault (generic default) from data-default, you could try to use GHC.Generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one option is to use generics, either the vanilla version or a helper package like [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-} -- derive stock, anyclass stuff
{-# LANGUAGE ImportQualifiedPost #-} -- GHC >= 8.10
import GHC.Generics
import Generics.SOP qualified as SOP
import Generics.SOP.NP (pure_NP)

data Foo
  = MkFoo
      { field1 :: Int,
        field2 :: Bool
      }
  deriving stock (Generic)
  deriving anyclass (SOP.Generic)

allundef :: Foo
allundef = SOP.productTypeTo $ pure_NP undefined
```